# Lg g4 battery problems

Tags: battery, battery-life, lg, lg-g4

My LG g4 has recently started losing battery very quickly and it is charging slowly with its original charger, sometimes it doesn't even charge. So I want to know what caused this because   I want  to get a new battery for it and would like to prevent this from happening again.

Comment: Sounds like the battery but also can be several different things. Does it have warranty?

Comment: I'm sure it does

Comment: Send it in then. Let them check it.

Comment: Suggest add charging tag also. Next, you can down load [Ampere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gombosdev.ampere)  and see the current being fed when charged to confirm your view that sometimes it is NOT charging

Comment: What is charging tag?

Comment: The output on my charge says 5v on ampere I'm getting 4.2v

Comment: Charger appears to be fine. Regarding" charging tag", edit your question and the tag same way you added other tags (search or just type in tag section)

Answer (score 0):

Does it feel warm near the camera? I recently had a similar issue and when I checked battery usage the Exchange app was near the top.

My specific issue was that I was using the default email app to retrieve my hotmail emails. There must be some recent bug in the software to accomplish this because my battery was draining in 3 hours from a full charge.

My solution was to:
1) remove my hotmail account from the phone.
2) stop and disable the Exchange app
3) download the Outlook app and use that for Microsoft based email accounts.

My battery life is now better than it ever was. I hope this helps.

Comment: I recently cleared up storage space and that seemed to help a little, I still have trouble with charging it so I assume it's my cord.